# Refresh the page after 90 seconds after clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

May I know if it is possible to refresh a page 90 seconds later after clicking a button.

Scenario:

At 10:10:00, a person click a button on my website. The button will show some information in the current page.

At 10:11:30, (which is 90 seconds later) the page refresh itself.

I can't seems to find any thing about this. Mostly, I see pages that show how to refresh the same page without pressing a button.

The button that I am referring to use `<input type="submit"></input` and not the normal `<button>` and therefore the page will refresh immediately.

Comment: Try looking up how to "refresh the page" and "how to do something after a time delay" and combining them.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout

Comment: Research setTimeout()

Comment: Try to split up your problem: _"How do I run code on button press"_, _"How do I run a function after a delay"_, and _"How do I reload a page."_ (Literally Google those sentences.) Then combine the functionalities you find.

Comment: @Sasse, what keyword should I use to search for this information?

Comment: "a onclick settimeout" maybe

Comment: You can do this using jquery for auto refresh page with timer.

Comment: @Cerbrus, my button is using `<input>` and not `<button>` and therefore the page will refresh immediately when the `<input>` button is clicked, which I only want it to refresh after 90 seconds.

Comment: @user275517 — So as well as the original problem you asked about, you also want to a submit button to run JavaScript instead of submitting the form. That's also easy to google.

Answer (score 1):

Use [window.setTimeOut](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) for that.

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click",function () {
  var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {
      alert("That was 2 secs slow!");
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">delayed alert</button>
```

Comment: Question isn't tagged with jQuery.

Comment: @Cerbrus : jquery was used to demo the functionality. `Window.setTimeout` is not jquery.